# LISTAGG query in Oracle split in batches

Tags: sql, oracle, batch-processing, listagg

I want to get a list of tables group by Schema and split the list of tables in batches, in Oracle Database (19.3).

Example:
I have 10 tables (A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J) which belong to HR schema.
with the query that I have I get this output
`Select Schema, LISTAGG(Table_Name) FROM SchemaInfo GROUP BY Schema`

| Schema | Tables |
| --- | --- |
| HR | A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J |

I would like split the group in batches of 5 elements and get an ouptput like this:

| Schema | Tables |
| --- | --- |
| HR | A,B,C,D,E |
| HR | F,G,H,I,J |

Are there any way to get this output? I have something similar for SQL but in Oracle is not working the same approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's probably an easier way, but here's an example I did with `all_tables`:

```
select owner, listagg(table_name, ',') 
from (
    select owner, table_name, floor(row_number() over (partition by owner order by table_name)/5) as batch
    from all_tables)
group by owner, batch
order by owner, batch
```

With your table, it would look like:

```
select Schema, listagg(table_name, ',') as Tables
from (
    select Schema, table_name, floor(row_number() over (partition by Schema order by table_name)/5) as batch
    from SchemaInfo)
group by Schema, batch
order by Schema, batch
```

Comment: Thanks. This is very useful. I applied it in listagg in snowflake as well